# What are the physical conditions for general ohms law?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, condensed-matter, electrical-resistance

A problem presents Ohm's law as $$\vec{J}=\sigma \vec{E}$$ where $\sigma$ is the conductivity given by a scalar. The problem asks what physical conditions must be satisfied for the equation to hold.

I understand that the material must be isotropic for the conductivity to be represented by a scalar instead of a tensor. What other physical conditions must apply?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most general form of the ohm law would be $J_i = \sigma_{ij}(x) E_j$. In the most general case, the conductivity is a tensor that depends on the position. Note that in the most general case, $J$ and $E$ are not parallel.

If the material is isotropic, then $J$ and $E$ are parallel and $\sigma$ is just a scalar function dependent on position. If now the material is homogeneous, $\sigma$ will no longer depend on $x$ and you get the usual ohm's law $J = \sigma E$.

Note that the actual value of $\sigma$ may depend on a number of different things like the temperature of the conductor.

Answer (score 0):

A trivial condition is that the temperature should be constant with current. An important one is that the mean free path of the charge carriers should be much shorter than the distance between the contacts.